# Gmail api how to convert date time from string?

Tags: .net, gmail

i dont know how to convert dynamic string timezone, when i get date time from gmail api.
i had received this data

```
message 1 : Tue, 24 Nov 2015 00:54:43 -0800
message 2 : Sat, 21 Nov 2015 03:04:58 +0000 (UTC)
message 3 : Thu, 7 May 2015 10:48:27 +0700
```

i want to convert string to datetime at S.E. Asia Standard Time (GMT+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta.

Comment: just wondering if you got solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at Timezone conversions, you should look at [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org) API.

Otherwise, you would have to write some C# conversion routines.  There are probably many examples out there.  Just be aware that older code might work with GMT and not UTC as the new servers are UTC now.  You will have to change them.